# Sign in for one time to different projects using laravel

Tags: php, web, laravel, laravel-4

I am using [laravel 4](http://laravel.com) framework in web development of my projects. I have 5 different applications (blog, school management, newspaper .... ). These application have separate logic so it's obviously should be separated into different projects each having its database.

**The problem is**

***These applications  share some of the users between them.***

Details:

In My case if a user wants to enter any of the application he should login first. which means he needs to login 5 times if he want to visit the 5 applications.

So what I want for users is to login **just once** in any of the 5 applications and so the user can jump from one application to another without another sign in.

*Note: The applications are on the same server and domain*

I am thinking in sharing the session between the projects. Is that a possible or a right way to do the task?

If yes, how can this be done in laravel?

If not. How such task can be solved also in laravel?

Comment: Can you share some information about the setup? It it something that's going to run on one server, is it going to run on one domain etc?

Comment: yes it will run on the same server and domain.

Comment: if I were you, I would try to use one application (it's the same server and domain) and 5 different layout templates.

Comment: What do you mean by layout templates ? If you mean UI. I have 5 different applications (blog, school management, newspaper .... ). these application have seperat logic so it's obviously should be separated into different projects. But they have the same users

Answer (score 1):

These are three options you have, and my advise on which to choose:

**1. Use one application and include all the logic**
You can create different libraries/modules for the application logic of the different elements in you code library. This is by far the easiest solution.

**2. Use multiple applications but share sessions**
Sharing sessions between applications is another option. It might not be a completely safe/stable solution but you could certainly make it work, and it is definitely a lot less work than option 3.

**3. Use multiple applications with a single-signon/login solution like OAuth 2**
The most difficult solution, but a very nice one, would be to set up an OAuth 2 server and implement OAuth 2 (client) in each of the applications. All the big guys (Google, Yahoo, Facebook) implement this system and it is very flexible, stable and safe.

In your situation I'ld go for option 1, because you want to run something on a single domain.